# Событие на input

Tags: javascript, события

В общем задача
необходимо создать форму состоящую из двух строк.

- 1-я строка: пользователь сайта вводит сумму
- 2-я строка: отображается это значение умноженое  на определенное число.

Пробовал сделать так:

```js
function countCharPass(val) {
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  if (quantity == "") {
    alert("Вы не указали суму");
  } else {
    cena = 440;
    stoimost = quantity * cena;
    document.getElementById('vivod').value.innerHTML = "Стоимость равна: " + stoimost + " р.";
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h3>Расчет стоимости</h3>
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" onkeyup="countCharPass(this)  value=" " placeholder="Введите суму для обмена ">
    <input type="text " id="vivod " name="vivod "  value=" " placeholder=" ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
function countCharPass(val) {
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  if (quantity == "") {
    alert("Вы не указали суму");
  } else {
    cena = 440;
    stoimost = quantity * cena;
    document.getElementById('vivod').value = "Стоимость равна: " + stoimost + " р.";
  }

}
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px; /* Задал ширину input-ам для наглядности */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Расчет стоимости</h3>
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" onkeyup="countCharPass(this)" value="" placeholder="Введите суму для обмена ">
<input type="text" id="vivod" name="vivod" value="" placeholder="">
```

Что поправил:

- Убрал лишние пробелы из идентификатора (`id`), типа (`type`) и имени (`name`) в HTML разметке
- Заменил `document.getElementById('vivod').value.innerHTML` на `document.getElementById('vivod').value` в JavaScript
- Увеличил ширину `input` элементов в CSS (не обязательно)